# Calculating the Electric Field Inside a Conductor with Two Cavities

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electric-fields, gauss-law

[image]

For this problem I am stuck on how to calculate the electric field. I know to apply Gauss' Law:
$$\oint \overrightarrow{ E} \cdot \overrightarrow {dA} = \frac{q_{enclosed}}{\epsilon_0}$$
$$E(4\pi r^2) = \frac{Q + -Q}{\epsilon_0}$$
I don't know $r$, but knowing that the $Q's$ are equal magnitude can this be stated that the electric field inside is zero?

Comment: Is the answer E?

Comment: That's what I am trying to verify, but I don't know if my approach is valid.

Comment: I am writing an answer wait

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider a point $D$ on in the *meat* of the conductor as shown.

[image]

We know that field inside the *meat* of a conductor is zero. So, electric field at $D$ is zero for all positions of $D$. Hence, the distribution on the outer surface of the sphere must be uniform so that it behaves like a shell. Also, the net charge on the surface is equal to the net charge inside a conductor. Hence, you may replace the conductor by an uncharged sphere to analyze Electric field and Potential outside the conductor.

So, your answer is $0$.